# How to compute the exact universe branches in many worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, decoherence

Many worlds interpretation says that, whenever a system's state gets decohered over time, such that no interference between the decohered states is possible anymore, the universe branches, with there being universes corresponding to every possible decohered state.

Now, consider a system inside a system inside a third system. The outermost system has a human observer in it. The middle system works like an environment for the innermost system.

The innermost system is initially in a superpositon of states. As the state is evolving, suppose it gets entangled with the middle system.

Over time, the the innermost system's state gets decohered into a sum of non-interfering states. Now, according to MWI, the universe should branch now.

The human observer in the outermost system will end up in one of the branches. Just before the branching, the human observer had been describing the two inner systems as a superposition:

$$\sum _{i,j} c_{ij} |Inner _i\rangle |Middle _j \rangle$$ $....(1)$

$|Inner_i\rangle$ and $|Middle_j\rangle$ form a basis of the innermost system and the middle system respectively.

After the branching, the human observer should describe the system as:

$$\sum _{j} d_j|Middle _j\rangle |Inner _{0}\rangle$$ $...(2)$

**I want to know an algorithm to compute $(2)$ from $(1)$, assuming that $(1)$ satisfies the conditions of universe branching**. I understand that there will be no deterministic algorithm, but there must be some relation between $d_j$ and $c_{ij}$

**Also, about "Schroedinger's Cat"**: There the middle system is the cat's atoms while the innermost system is the quantum poison releaser.

According to MWI, the cat ends up as alive or dead in two universe branches **before** the human opens the box. That means the human was in the same branch before he opened the box. That means that, before opening the box, the box's state was:

$$|Cat _{dead} \rangle |Poison _{released} \rangle$$ or $$|Cat _{alive}\rangle |Poison _{unreleased}\rangle$$

But the above requires the cat's state to already have been decohered into alive or dead before the box is opened. This seems wrong because Cat is the environment here, and decoherence does not apply to the environment, but only to the inner most system (i.e. the poison releaser).

The only resolution I see is to describe the cat's atoms in a superposition until the box is opened. A few moments after the box is opened, the cat entangles with the human's environment, decoheres, and the universe branches again to make cat's state concretely alive or dead. A few moments later, the human's state also gets entangled with the outside envrionment, the universe branches again, and only then the human becomes classical and realises the cat's state.

Is this really what MWI is saying about Schroedinger's cat?

Comment: The state of our eyes becomes correlated with the state of the cat just like the state of the cat becomes correlated with the state of the poison. This can be modelled as $| \mathrm{Human}_{\mathrm{ignorant}} \rangle (|C_a, P_u \rangle + | C_d, P_r \rangle)$ evolving unitarily to $| \mathrm{Human}_{\mathrm{happy}}, C_a, P_u \rangle + | \mathrm{Human}_{\mathrm{sad}}, C_d, P_r \rangle$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan why are you assuming the box's state, prior to box opening, to be $|C_a, P_u\rangle +|C_dP_r\rangle$. I think, according to MWI, the universe has already branched before opening the box (because the Cat decohered the Poison's state). So the Poison's state should already be collapsed before the box opening.

Comment: Well that's your misconception right there. Many Worlds is precisely the belief that states never collapse.

Answer (score 3):

This scenario of multiple observers in nested systems is discussed in [Everett's thesis](https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf) starting on page 4. *"The question of the consistency of the scheme arises if one contemplates regarding the observer and his object-system as a single (composite) physical system. Indeed, the situation becomes quite paradoxical if we allow for the existence of more than one observer."*

Everett's interpretation does *not*, in fact, posit any extra universes, or any special process by which their creation is triggered. This is precisely the 'Collapse of the Wavefunction' paradigm that Everett sought to get rid of. The idea of there being 'Many Worlds' was invented afterwards when others tried to explain the idea to the general public - when you consider what a quantum observer would experience 'from the inside' as it were, it would look *as if* each outcome occurred in a separate world, the possible outcomes *all* happening in separate universes running in parallel to one another. But this is not the mechanism Everett proposed.

Nor did he say it had to do with interacting with a complex thermodynamic *environment*, turning a quantum state into a collapsed classical one through sheer complexity. This appears to be trying to re-introduce wavefunction collapse. Everett's mechanism works just as well with simple observer systems as with vastly complicated ones.

What Everett said is that when two quantum systems interact, they enter a *joint* state which is a superposition of independently-evolving orthogonal states, in which the state of the observer and observed are *correlated*. You can no longer talk about the observed state of the observed system in isolation - it is only defined *relative to* the state of the observer.

The components of the superposition don't interact with one another, cannot see one another, and so can each make the assumption that all the others have somehow *vanished*, leaving only one. This is the 'wavefunction collapse'. We have no concrete, detailed explanation for how or why they vanish, and making the assumption breaks locality and determinism which would normally be enough to finish off any other theory, but it restores our comfortingly classical 'one outcome' picture of the world. And since we have no experimental way to tell whether or not they *have* vanished, this is merely an 'Interpretation' and physicists can believe what they like about it.

So take our nested 'Schrodinger's box' set-up. A particle is in superposition of up and down, and our observers inside and outside the box are in states of ignorance. The observer inside the box interacts with the particle. The two enter a joint state in which what the observer observed is correlated with the state of the particle. There is a superposition of an observer seeing 'up', and an observer seeing 'down'. These two components do not interact, they cannot 'see' one another, so it is *as if* they were in separate worlds, but only from the point of view of the inner observer. As far as the outer observer is concerned, they are still in uncollapsed superposition.

Now the outer observer opens the box and interacts with the inner observer. They enter a joint state with two mutually-invisible components, in one of which they both see 'up', in the other they both see 'down'. To the inner observer, this looks like a classical transfer of information. To the outer observer, it looks like wavefunction collapse. But in fact they're both still in superposition, both outcomes are still part of the state.

The universe only appears to split as far as an individual observer is concerned. From the point of view of other people, the collapse into separate universes hasn't happened yet. Or looked at another way, the universes were already separate right from the start - the superposition of 'up' and 'down' of the unobserved particle is *already* two separate worlds from the particle's 'sum-over-histories' point of view.

Universes splitting is a bad way of thinking about the physics. It works well as an explanation of what being part of a superposition of states would *look like* 'from the inside', but it causes immense confusion if taken as more than just a very loose illustration. People start asking questions about what triggers the split, and how fast does *the rip* propagate, and where does the energy to build another entire universe come from, and we're back to believing in 'wavefunction collapse' by the back door.

Reading Everett's thesis is the best way to find out what the original MWI really says. There are lots of different versions that have subsequently branched off from it, many of them based on misunderstandings of what Everett was saying. They are worth evaluating as theories in their own right - people have identified problems with the original proposal that they have tried to solve in various ways - but you have to know the original to be able to see where they deviate from it.

Comment: This is one hell of a first post. I wish I could upvote it twice.

Comment: hmm but what is the rule for "what terms in the superposition get dropped out"? I read on other Physics SE posts that the rule was that the terms should be non-interfering, and that is why decoherence enters MWI because it creates non-interfering superpositions. Is there some other rule to determine what superposition terms get vanished?

Comment: Ryder Rude - it depends on the detailed nature of the interaction, and of the $10^{25}$-particle observer. When classical oscillators interact, they enter 'normal modes of vibration'; a sum of independently oscillating solutions. The principle here is similar. I gave a hand-wavey outline in a post here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720347

Comment: This all seem to make sense until you wonder what 'interacts' means in this context - because replacing the unphysical notion of 'collapse' with a nebulous notion of (entangling) 'interaction' does not bring any extra clarity to the issue. How is 'entering a joint state' any less handwaving than 'collapsing a wavefunction'? As soon as there is a point where *something happens*, be it 'collapsing a superposition' or 'entering a joint state', we get back the old measurement problem: why is there a non-unitary evolution of the quantum state upon measurement?

Comment: "Universes splitting is a bad way of thinking about the physics... Reading Everett's thesis is the best way to find out what the original MWI really says." Yes! +1.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin Entering a joint state is unitary. If you take two electrons in the ground state of an impenetrable box at $t = 0$, the Schroedinger equation for the $1/r$ potential between them will show that their state becomes entangled for any $t > 0$.

Comment: Stephane Rollandin - there *isn't* a non-unitary evolution of the quantum state upon measurement. There is a *unitary* evolution into a superposition of mutually non-interacting states. It only *looks* non-unitary if you assume all the other components vanish when you can no longer see them. And the evolution into non-interacting 'normal modes of vibration' is an unavoidable consequences of oscillators interacting. Basically because when you diagonalise the interacting equations of motion the eigenvectors are orthogonal. Sorry, I didn't have time, space, or scope to explain everything here.

Comment: "This [environmental decoherence] appears to be trying to re-introduce wavefunction collapse." - no, what it's trying to do is model a process that demonstrably occurs in the real world, which is what physicists do for a living. "The components of the superposition don't interact with one another, cannot see one another [...]" - if that were true, there would be no evidence for quantum mechanics. It's true only when the which-path information can't be erased, e.g., because of thermodynamic irreversibility. You do need more than entanglement to make this picture work.

Comment: What did this answer refer to as an attempt to re-introduce wavefunction collapse? Not environmental decoherence but *the assumption that large and small cases of it obey different rules*. Also, components of a superposition only need to be observable by something, not by each other. The Stern-Gerlach experiment shows evidence for quantum mechanics but it would not if we sent ourselves through the magnetic field instead of silver atoms.